# What does "sobadito" mean?

Tags: palabras-raras, definiciones, comida, costa-rica

Here is one more food word I collected in Costa Rica:

> `sobadito`

In my notes I have only written that it has some connection with food. It's from about five years ago so I don't recall anything more. I have checked that it's not in the DRAE, Wikipedia, Wiktionary, Larousse Gran Diccionario, Google Translate, etc. It does get Google hits but many seem to be people's nicknames. Nothing else stands out.

**Does anybody know what "sobadito" is?**

Comment: It's possible that you mean "sobao"?

Comment: Where have you seen it?? Maybe it's the diminutive of '[sobao][1]', but it's a type of bread typical from Spain, so I'm not sure if 'sobadito' is referring to it.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobao

Comment: I don't think so. "Sobao" looks more unusual to me so I woul've collected that for sure if I'd seen it. It is however possible that it could be a variant or diminutive. What does "sobao" mean? Is it costarriquense?

Comment: @ElBoletaireUnderave: As mentioned in the question I collected this word in Costa Rica, not in Spain \-:

Comment: Sorry, when I said "where have you seen it" I wasn't referring to the country but rather to the business or whatever where you saw it (p. eg. a restaurant)

Comment: Sorry @ElBoletaireUnderave I used to write these words on tiny scraps like the backs of receipts so I often didn't have much space for context. Whenever I tried to use a proper notebook it proved unwieldy or impractical and didn't end up getting used much. )-:

Comment: If you search for both "sobao" and "sobadito", you get some interesting [results](http://aossesc.blogspot.com/2003/11/el-gancho-la-choca-el-sobato-y-la-chey.html) such as: "El tenientismo que más recientemente aprendí es el sobaí­to (sobadito, para los más puristas). Se usa como diminutivo de sobao, y pensé que era usado en forma despectiva, pero me equivocaba. El sobao, según mi viejo, es aquel al que le andan pegando siempre (que le soban el cuero); yo había entendido que sobao era el que pasaba borracho siempre. Pues bien, no: el sobaí­to tenientino es como decir ganchito, socito, viejito."

Comment: Very nice find @JonEricson! It seems the two are variants at least lexically but that excerpt doesn't seem to deal with a food sense. So now we only have to figure out whether the two variants also refer to the same food or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I google searched "sobadito comida" (please hold the easy jokes:P)and all the results I found refered both to "sobaos" and others refered to "bizcohos de soletilla" or "Melindros" but people called them sobaditos in some reciepes.

[image: Sobaos]

[image: bizcochos]

Comment: Indeed food words vary greatly as they move around, sometimes little by little, sometimes by leaps and bounds. Both their sounds and their meanings are slippery. That's what I love about them (-:

Answer (score 2):

'Sobar' is used also as "to knead".

So a "sobadito" could means a biscuit of dough well kneaded.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its derived from ["sobado"](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=sobado) ("well-worn", "shabby") by adding the diminutive suffix -ito. I don't think you can really express it in English exactly, and the particular meaning of the diminutive may depend on the content (e.g. "a bit shabby" seems to be a possibility).

Comment: As a clarification: I propose that it could have been used as an adjective describing the quality of food, not a particular food.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will be a particular food. There were lots of foods in Mexico and Central America with funny names. My favourite was one in Panama called ["ropa vieja"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ropa_vieja). In fact it was one of my favourite Panamanian foods as well as one of my favourite food words in the Spanish language. And having eating it several times I can say it's definitely not the literal meaning (-:

Comment: [There are a couple of Google hits I've found with "sobadito" used in connection with food](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=sobadito+food+OR+comer+OR+comida&um=1&hl=en&safe=off&source=lnms&ei=aS7MToSYLYje8AP_q6TADw&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=1&ved=0CC8Q_AUoAA&biw=853&bih=447). The best one is of [a kind of ceviche](http://mackzully.smugmug.com/Other/Peru/4679385_SHgAw/30/276700394_iqs7P#276700394_iqs7P), but nothing is really conclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Could you be referring to a 'sudado de mariscos' which is a kind of a soup but thicker?  Your word may be a diminutive of this.